# Django does not honor ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, mariadb

This is my model:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    ...
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ...
```

This is the generated SQL, according to `sqlmigrate` (and to manual inspection of the database):

```
ALTER TABLE `myapp_subscriber` ADD CONSTRAINT `myapp_subscriber_tenant_id_b52815ee_fk_myapp_tenant_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tenant_id`) REFERENCES `myapp_tenant` (`id`);
```

I was expecting something like [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-keys-examples):

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

With the `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

`MySql` (`MariaDB` actually) complains when I delete:

```
SQL Error (1451): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Which makes sense since there is no `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.

Why is `Django 2.1.5` not honoring the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause?

Comment: you checked your database privileges?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete):

> `on_delete` doesn’t create a SQL constraint in the database. Support for
>   database-level cascade options may be implemented later

It will perform the cascade in Django itself, so if you delete a `Tenant` object using Django `delete()` your `Subscriber` object will also be deleted. But not if you do it in SQL.

Comment: What are my options if I want to do it at the SQL level?

Comment: In what sense? You want to add the constraint to your table so it always does it? Or you want to perform a SQL query that deletes your tenant row and cascades?

Comment: Those are my options! :) I will go for the first one, altering the DB with my own hackish migration then.

Comment: You can use [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) in your migration file. But I would actually advise you against doing this, as this will introduce unexpected behavior to your application. You shouldn't have to use raw SQL that often that you need to implement it at the DB level. At least, add a mega-big mega-bold comment in your model for future colleagues to know what's going on :-)

Comment: Note: `manage.py shell` is a better way to directly access objects than `manage.py dbshell` if you need to manually do stuff.

Comment: We have some dynamic filtering coming at the API level which can be parsed to SQL but not translated to django queries (without implementing a fully-fledged domain language to translate our filtering specification to the django DAL). That's why I am using raw SQL, and why I need to cascading to happen at the SQL level.

Comment: Actually having the cascade both on SQL and ORM probably won't do harm, since if you go through the ORM, Django will delete the `Subscription`s first and the SQL cascade won't have anything to do once the `Tenant` gets deleted. Just keep the default `on_delete=CASCADE` on your model as well.

Comment: I was actually thinking about that. Good tip, thanks.